# How to update a component after updating props react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

how to update a component after updating props? 
I have the following component structure:

```
MyList.js 
render() {
 return(
  <ComponentList products={props.products}>
  <ComponentBoard product={props.product[i]} //send choosen product(1) from list(100 products)
 )
}
```

and next components have 2 similar component contentRow

```
ComponentList.js (
same(
 <contentRow > list .map() //100 contentRow
)

ComponentBoard.js
same(
 <contentRow > // 1 contentRow
)
```

in the component componentRow there are fields that display and through redux change the data in the store, for example, the username.

And when I open the ComponentBoard component and change the value in the ComponentRov field, the value in the ComponentList> componentRow should also change.

For a better understanding:

ComponentList is a table of ComponentsRow, when clicked to row, That opens the ComponentBoard window, in which there is also a componentRow.

Question: how to update the data that is displayed in componentList from componentBoard? they have similar props from 1 store

Answer (score 2):

When serializing `props` as initial state you should listen for changes in `props` and update the `state` accordingly. In class based components you use `componentDidUpdate` in functional components you can achieve the same result with an `useEffect` listening for changes in a given `prop`

```
const Component = ({ foo }) =>{
    const [state, setState] = useState(foo) //initial state

    useEffect(() =>{
        setState(foo) //everytime foo changes update the state
    },[foo])
}
```

The `class` equivalent

```
class Component extends React.Component{
    state = { foo : this.props.foo } // initial state

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
          if(prevProps.foo !== this.props.foo)
              this.setState({ foo : this.props.foo }) //everytime foo changes update the state
    }
}
```

Comment: i try componentDidUpdate 
before writing question, but component not update. I change "firstname" in global redux store, in componentBoard name change, but in list nothing changed

Answer (score 2):

for a better understanding of React, I recommend you read 
[React Life Cycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

the general idea is to make your list into the state of the MyList.js , that way, u can update it through a function in Mylist.js and pass it as a prop to the ComponentBoard . Now you can change the state of MyList and when that changes, so does ComponentList.

```
class MyList extends Component {
constructor(){
super();
this.state = {
// an array of objects 
}}

    handleBoardChange = () => {  some function using this.setState }
// the rest of your Mylist class
}
```